# Problem blurring UIImage

Tags: iphone, image, blur

```
 UIView *myView = self;
    CALayer *layer = [myView layer];
    [layer setRasterizationScale:0.25];
    [layer setShouldRasterize:YES];
```

I found this code somewhere except the problem is that when I use it it says the methods are not found. Also, when I type layer. and press escape to see all the properties for autocomplete I see none so is can you please help me figure out the problem, maybe I'm not importing something? Please help and thanks in advance

Comment: Fixed just have to import quartzcore

Comment: if you fixed then put it as answer..and accept..

Comment: I have to wait 7 hours since I don't have enough rep

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to import Quartz-core framework from the existing framework and add it to your project,and import  in the .h class.

Answer (score 1):

Hello Aspyn,

```
       You will try this code this will help you

      First of all add QuartzCore.framework from existing framework and .m file you import this framework as follow
      #import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
      UIView *myView = self;
      CALayer *layer = [myView layer];
      [layer setRasterizationScale:0.25];
      [layer setShouldRasterize:YES];
      [layer setContentsScale:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit];
```